# Getting Z component from point in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, identify

I am trying to get the z value from PointZ geometry from an ArcGIS map service, using the identify task. Setting `returnGeometry=true` only returns XY even though the Z value is there.

I can see the z value when I query via the REST API, using the `returnZ=true` parameter, so I know the data is there.

After researching all the options for the [IdentifyParameters](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/identifyparameters-amd.html) class, I fear that what I am trying to achieve is not possible using this approach, even though there is a `returnZ` option in other APIs.

So **how** do I get the z-value into my identify window?

Comment: I think this is because in **ArcGIS API for JavaScript V3** library, constructor dont have z value (same for m)  as properties. I just look at [point object](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/point-amd.html) But your can use it on **ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4.0** library. Look at API Reference for [geometry Point](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/beta/api-reference/esri-geometry-Point.html)

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will just have to wait for v4.0 to get out of Beta.

Comment: This is outrageous!! For most of our customers, Z-values are very important (and has been for over 20 years...). For some data, they even have 2 different z-values to specify both top and bottom of the feature! It is unbeleivable that this is not supported until v4!

Comment: Is it possible to use rest api that returns the result as plain json instead of wrapped arcgis point geometry object?